# Couchdb document/function

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb, couchdb-futon

In a document with the following information:

```
{
  "address": [{
    "Street": "123 xyz", 
    "City": "Belmont"
  }]
}
```

How can I view the name of the cities. Is this correct:

```
function(doc) {
  emit(doc.address.City,null);
}
```

It returns only `null`. I wanted to see the name "Belmont".
Any help with be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In your data, `address` is an array, so it does not have a `City` property.

If you only have one address in your data:

```
{
  "address": {
    "Street": "123 xyz", 
    "City": "Belmont"
  }
}
```

Getting `/{database}/_design/{ddoc}/_view/{view}` should return:

```
{"rows":[
  {"key":"Belmont", "id":"{id}", "value":null}
]}
```

As a side note, please note that you can also get `/{database}/_design/{ddoc}/_view/{view}?include_docs=true`:

```
{"rows":[
  {"key":"Belmont", "id":"{id}", "value":null, "doc":{
    "address": {
      "Street": "123 xyz", 
      "City": "Belmont"
    }
  }}
]}
```

Last but not least, if you really need multiple adresses in your data, you can send them all:

```
function(o) {
  for each (var a in o.address) {
    emit(a.City);
  }
}
```

Comment: { "name":"jack",
  "address": [{
    "Street": "123 xyz", 
    "City": "Belmont"
  }]
} if i also had name will i be able to see the name alongside the city, based on the last function you have written. thanks for your help. i want to see the name is the key and city as the value.

Comment: With `include_docs=true`, you indeed get the full document (with "jack" and all of his adresses). What you need to remember is that the `key` is what you use to select or sort the rows, the `value` is either the result of a complex computation you want to keep, or a a partial result you want to aggregate with a `reduce` function, the `doc` is, well, the whole document.